# receive multiples ids by ajax using laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I get from ajax request multiple ids by using the followinf script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#numero_projet').change(function(){


       var id_projet = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");

      $('#generer').click(function(){

        var checkValues = [];
         
      $.each($("input[name='casting_checked[]']:checked"), function() {            
      checkValues.push($(this).data('id'));
    });
         var selectedvalues = checkValues;
         console.log(selectedvalues);
      $.ajax({
                url: "/generer/"+selectedvalues+"/"+id_projet,
                type: 'get',
                headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
               
                    data: 'selectedvalues=' + selectedvalues,id_projet:id_projet,
                  
                         
                    success: function(response) {
                              var selectedvalues = checkValues;
                                window.location.href = 'generer/' + selectedvalues+'/'+id_projet;

                    }
              
            });
          });
      });
   
   });
 
</script>
```

the `console.log(selectedvalues);` gives : `(3) [15, 17, 19]`

In My controller , I have :

```
public function generer(Request $request){

$projets_casting = Projet_Casting::whereIn('id_casting',explode(",", $request->selectedvalues))->where('id_projet',$request->id_projet)->get();


           $callback = function() use($projets_casting) {

            foreach ($projets_casting as $projet_casting) {
            
                $id_contrat  = $projet_casting->id_contrat;
               
                 dd($id_contrat);
              
      }
    };
          return Response::stream($callback, 200);
  }
```

The problem is the `projets_casting` returns multiple rows according to the ids received by ajax request so the `dd($id_contrat)` should also returns a multiple values , value of each row returned by `projets_casting`. while in this case ans with this code I get only the value of one row and not of all rows of  `projets_casting`.

If you have any idea please help

Comment: I suggest you to use POST request

Comment: Do you want all values of `$id_contrat`?

Comment: `dd()` means "*die and dump*", so the script will terminate immediately after dumping only the first result.